Filament: How to get Repeater's "subtotal" item value and then update to "maintotal" field outside of Repeater during delete action?
How to get Repeater's "subtotal" item value and then update to "maintotal" field outside of Repeater during delete action?
TextInput::make('maintotal'),
Repeater::make('InvoiceItems')
    ->schema([
        TextInput::make('subtotal')
    ])
    ->deleteAction()


did you look at https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/forms/fields/repeater#customizing-the-repeater-item-actions

You have to use live property on the field inside the repeater (works also with live on the repeater itself):
use Filament\Forms\Get;
use Filament\Forms\Set;

...

Forms\Components\Repeater::make('items')
       ->schema([
           Forms\Components\TextInput::make('item')
                ->required()
                ->live(),
           ])
       ->addAction(function (Get $get, Set $set) {
           $total = collect($get('items'))->values()->pluck('item')->sum();
           $set('total', $total);
       }),

inspect what $get('items') is: in my case is an array of array with a single key "item" like the field name.
